# remote() и deleteOne()

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

Есть код

Вариант 1

```
 Client
        .find({name: body.deleteName}) 
        .remove().then(() => {console.log("Removed!")});
```

Вариант 2

```
 Client
        .deleteOne({name: body.deleteName}, (err) => console.log(err));
```

Этот код идентичен, разве что с одни отличием. Вариант 2 удаляет первый документ, который соответствует условию из коллекции.
 Но при втором варианте на фронте появляется такая ошибка

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: fullData is not defined
```

ссылаясь на этот код

```
$('.button-delete').click(() => {
  let delBody = {};

  delBody.deleteName = $('#delete-name').val();

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:3000/deleteClient",
    crossDomian: true,
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(delBody)
  }).done(data => {
    $(".form-select").load("../database", () => {
      for (let i = 0; i < fullData.length; i++) {
        $(".form-select").append(
          $(`<option value = ${i}>${fullData[i].name}</option>`)
        );
      }
    });
  });
});
```

C чем вообще это cвязано? Почему с первым вариантом работает, а со вторым нет?

Comment: Если судить по приведенному коду, то можно предположить, что, поскольку в нем действительно нигде не определяется переменная `fullData`, то в первом случае часть `.done(...` не выполняется, например, из-за того, что `$.ajax()` возвращает ошибку.

Comment: К сожалению нет. Ajax работает полностью исправно. Лишь поменяв метод удаления, возникает такая ошибка. А переменная fullData определяется выше, я ее не включил в код)

Comment: А Вы все-таки для уверенности 1) выведите в консоль эту самую `data`; 2) добавьте всё же ещё и `.fail(...`.